# Filter table with text box dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Currently I am trying to only display rows to the user if the row contains something the user searched for. An example of this would be if the user searched for poop they would be shown all the rows that contain poop in them. For some reason however, my search is only taking the info from the last column of the row and not the whole row.

```js
$("#searchInput").keyup(function() {
 var val = $(this).val();
    
 $("#searchTable tr td").each(function(i) {
 var content = $(this).html();
  if (content.toLowerCase().indexOf(val) == -1) {
   $(this).parent().hide();
  } else {
   $(this).parent().show();
  }
 });
});
```

```html
<div>
        <input type="text" id="searchInput" />
        <table id="searchTable">
            <tr>
                <td>test</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Latest</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Mest</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>test</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Best</td>
                <td>chest</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>chest</td>
                <td>poop</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>test</td>
                <td>poop</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Waste</td>
                <td>poop</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Test</td>
                <td>poop</td>
            </tr>
        </table>


    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now it works. Look only to the "tr" elements not to the "td tr" elements

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pCBe4/41/)

**js**

```
$("#searchInput").keyup(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();

    $("#searchTable tr").each(function(i) {
    var content = $(this).html();
        if (content.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) == -1) {
            $(this).hide();
        } else {
            $(this).show();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You answered it too fast! It's making me wait haha 4 more minutes

Comment: good answer, I was typing up the same thing as you submitted it. @CMcCoy You understand why right? The correct td was showing the row like you wanted, but then the non-matching td was hiding it on the next iteration.

Comment: @Wold I do now, thanks you for the explanation was still a little confused!

Comment: What if the user enters all capital letters? If you're going to make one lower case you have to make the other side of the equation lower case as well.

Comment: .text() would be better fit here than .html()

Comment: What would be the advantage of using .text() here?